# reading xml: can xpath read 2 fields?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm using SimpleXMLElement and xpath to try and read the `<subcategory><name>` from the xml at the very bottom. This code works.. but the stuff inside the `while` loop looks a little messy, and now I also want to get the `<subcategory><count>` and somehow pair it with its appropriate `<subcategory><name>`.

```
$names = $xml->xpath('/theroot/category/subcategories/subcategory/name/'); 
while(list( , $node) = each($names)) {
    echo $node; 
}
```

**My question: Is it possible to get this pairing while still using xpath since it looks like it can make the job easier?**

```
<theroot>
<category>
  <name>Category 1</name>
  <subcategories>
      <subcategory>
          <name>Subcategory 1.1</name>
          <count>18</count>
      </subcategory>
      <subcategory>
          <name>Subcategory 1.2</name>
          <count>29</count>
      </subcategory>
  </subcategories>
</category>

<category>
  <name>Category 2</name>
  <subcategories>
      <subcategory>
          <name>Subcategory 2.1</name>
          <count>18</count>
      </subcategory>
      <subcategory>
          <name>Subcategory 2.2</name>
          <count>29</count>
      </subcategory>
  </subcategories>
</category>
</theroot>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SimpleXML, and you know the exact layout, it might be easier to do this:

```
$subcategories = $xml->xpath('/theroot/category/subcategories/subcategory');
foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
    echo $subcategory->name.'='.$subcategory->count;
}
```

With XPath, you could ofcourse select all subnodes of `subcategory`, but pairing them back up could be more trouble then just foregoing xpath for the last node.